How to calculate the dBFS level using python sounddevice
I'm trying to get a decibel reading from an audio stream using the sounddevice library.
More specifically, I want to display the current level in a DAW like fashion.
According to this, most DAWs display either dBFS or LUFS levels in their meters. I'm interested in dbFS, because that seems to be the one more commonly used.
According to this, the dBFS level computes to
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) 

which can be simplified to
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal)) + 3.0103

The values coming from the sounddevice library with dtype='float32' are in a range between [-1,1]
Here's my code:
import sounddevice
import numpy as np

class SoundLevelReader(QObject):
    new_level = Signal(float)
    def sd_callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level
        # see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8785/how-to-compute-dbfs
        rms  = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.absolute(indata)**2))
        dBFS = 20 * np.log10(rms * np.sqrt(2))
        self.new_level.emit(dBFS)

def main():
    # ...
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    reader = SoundLevelReader()
    meter  = VolMeter(-60, 0)
    reader.new_level.connect(meter.set_meter_value)
    with sd.InputStream(callback=reader.sd_callback, dtype='float32', device=4, blocksize=5000):
        sys.exit(app.exec())

At first glance, the values seem reasonable. However, compared to my DAW (Logic Pro), my values are around 6dB lower and I do not understand why. I'm comparing the values of my DAW with the code above with a Sennheiser Profile USB-C microphone. Inside the DAW I didn't add any gain or effects. I only selected the input and that's it.
If a add a smudge factor to the log10() function, I can sort of match the levels, but I'd like to understand what the actual value is and where it comes from.
value_dBFS = 20*log10(dirty * rms(signal)) + 3.0103

Question:
Can someone explain, how to correctly calculate dBFS based on readings coming from the sounddevice python lib?

You seem to be certain that data is given in Pa. At least, computing 20*log10(rms/20e-6) with those 20e-6 being 20μPa, makes sense only if rms, and therefore indata is in Pa. I am no expert in sound, nor in sounddevice. But I am pretty sure data provided by sounddevice are not at all in this kind of unit.

Firstly because to have real units such as Pa, that would need to control the whole chain of transformation (mike changing Pa→volts, ADC changing volts→bits, alsa, pulseaudio, sounddevice doing all their own thing about gain, some by controling hardware, some by applying software scale. Then sounddevice calibrate depending on dtype used (-1.0 to 1.0 for floats, -1 and +1 being just described as "minimum and maximum value", regardless of any absolute physical unit meaning)

Ànd you have of course no control on some of those stages. Most are 100% transparent. Soundcard get some volts from the mike without any indication about what kind of Pa/V conversion it does. A mike is just a very simple passive (on mic input) component acting as a variable resistor, without indication "how variable". And no communication protocol whatsoever to communicated a mike ID, and look in a table what are its feature.

Secondly because, when playing at least, sounddevice explicitely guarantees no such absolute meaning of values. So I guess it is the same when recording. And thirdly, because once upon a time I saw people paying some fairly big amount of money to have some "absolute value" capture of sound. I guess that if a $6 logitech mike on a $10 Creative sound card could have done that,...

So not only I think you assume too much by assuming that those are Pa units (again doc only says -1 is "minimum" and +1 is "maximum", regardless of what is the range of sensors, let alone the rest of the chain). But I think that information needed to even build such an information isn't even available (but again, not an expert in sound. Plus, it has been a long time since the last period I dig in this sound chain, so it may have evolved since). If you need such measure, you probably will need to calibrate first the whole chain with some real calibration sound.

(And then, either never touch any gain parameter, nor from the mike, the soundcard, alsa, pulseaudio, ... ; or take time, when calibrating, to understand how those parameters impact the result)

In the meantime, I learned that the measure I want is dBFS. The reference measure of 20µPa is only relevant if you want to calculate a gain (or loss) in decibel compared to that reference. However, I'm still experiencing that my result is too low compared to what my DAW shows. I will edit the question.

Question revised to ask for dBFS specifically
